# Difference in Server UNIX time and device current time

Tags: java, android, unix-timestamp

I get Unix timestamp from server, it can be some order creation time:
1531740385

I need to show some data, 20 minutes after this time from server.

I tried this approach:

```
currentUnixTime = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
timeDifference = currentUnixTime - orderaddedtime;
  if(timeDifference<1160){
show();
}
```

But it doesn't work if i change the time in android settings or change the time zone. How to get exact time difference?

Comment: 20 minutes in millisecond is much more than 1160. Calculate (1000 * 60) is minute *20 is goal

Comment: @StanislavBondar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time